# Add custom xsi namespace with jsonix

Tags: javascript, json, xml, jsonix

How is it possible to add a custom xsi namespaces to a XML file with jsonix? We would like to achieve the following:

```
<network xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/XMLSchema ../../../Example/schema/Example.xsd">
```

The best thing we could get was this using namespace prefixes:

```
<network xmlns:schemaLocation="http://example.com/XMLSchema ../../../Example/schema/Example.xsd">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) (well, you know).

At the moment you can use the [attribute property](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Properties#attribute-property) or the [any attribute property](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Properties#any-attribute-property) to model `xsi:schemaLocation`, somethin like:

```
{
    type: 'attribute',
    name: 'schemaLocation',
    attributeName : { localPart: 'schemaLocation', namespaceURI : 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' }
    typeInfo: 'String'
}
```

Basically, just like any other normal attribute.

However, I think `xsi:schemaLocation` should be supported on the `Jsonix.Context` level. This **is not supported** at the moment, but I think this is how it should look like:

```
var context = new Jsonix.Context(mappings, {
    schemaLocations: {
        "http://example.com/XMLSchema": "../../../Example/schema/Example.xsd"
    }
});
```

Similar to [`namespacePrefixes`](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Configuring-Namespace-Prefixes), but mapping namespace URIs onto schema locations.

Please [file an issue](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/issues), if you'd like to have this feature.